# ViewController Calling External Object Method

Tags: ios, objective-c, c

Let me first explain the context here. I am developing an iOS 6.1 application using Xcode 4.6. I have created a table view controller in which I have connected 4 views. The first view is the `main` view, the one which I am working on.

Right now I have two buttons on the `main` view. A `yes` and a `no` button. I have created a `viewcontroller_main` subclass and connected it to my `main` view by altering its class in the  identity inspector.

I have created my own class `myclass` which has one function called `go`. In my `viewcontroller_main.h` I have added an `-(IBAction)button_no` and another for the yes. I then linked them by clicking the `main` view and connecting the functions to the buttons via the connections inspector.

Now here is where my problem is. My `yes` button currently just logs 'yes' to the console via NSLog i.e.

```
//viewcontroller_main.m

- (IBAction)button_yes {
    NSLog(@"Yes was pressed");
}
```

However, my `no` button creates an object `myclass* myname` and then it does `myname.go`. I have another `NSLog` function to display "no" in the `go` method implementation in the `myclass.m` file.

```
//viewcontroller_main.m

- (IBAction)button_no {
    myclass* myname;
    myname.go;
}

//myclass.m

- (void)go {
    NSLog(@"no was pressed")
}
```

How do you explain this behaviour? Why would I not see a console log when calling `myname.go`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, classes should always be capitalized. So you should use `ViewController_main` and `Myclass`.

Secondly, when you do `myclass* myname;` you are not creating an object. If you were to print out `myname` (`NSLog(@"%@", myname)`) you would find that it is nil. That being said, try something like:

```
myclass* myname = [[myclass alloc] init];
```

Comment: annnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnd I'm a noob.

Comment: haha, we were all there once! Hope you enjoy iOS dev! @MikeH.